# Angular 8 inject pipe into another pipe does not work

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular-dependency-injection

After upgrading from Angular 7 to Angular 8 my *pipe* stopped to work with error:

```typescript
    TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

      10 | export class APipe implements PipeTransform {
      11 |
    > 12 |   constructor(
         |               ^
      13 |     private readonly bPipe: BPipe,
      14 |     private readonly cPipe: CPipe) {}
```

or with similar error:

```
Error: Found non-callable @@iterator
```

Code of my pipe:

```typescript
@Pipe({
  name: 'aPipe'
})
export class APipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(
    private readonly bPipe: BPipe,
    private readonly cPipe: CPipe) {}

  transform(someValue: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!someValue) {
      return ' — ';
    }

    if (cond1) {
      return this.bPipe.transform(someValue, ...args);
    }
    else {
      return this.cPipe.transform(someValue, ...args);
    }

    return ' — ';
  }

}
```

Do I have to mark the pipe as `@Injectable()` explicitly in Angular8 or what is the issue?

Comment: Did you add pipes to `providers` array of the module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit

provide it in your module : [**Source**](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#the-pipetransform-interface)

<strike>Pipes aren't injectable. They're just usual classes.</strike>

This means that if you want a pipe into another, this will be done with

```
const cPipe = new CPipe(...);
```

Comment: This is wrong. You can inject a pipe in component, services, etc. Here's a working stackblitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdvz6q

Comment: Indeed, `If you choose to inject your pipe into a class, you must provide it in the providers array of your NgModule.`. Didn't know that ! ([source](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#the-pipetransform-interface))

Answer (score 0):

The answer was already given using links to the documentation. Here is the full example in case someone needs it.

Pipes that need to be injected somewhere should be provided in your module (most likely `app.module.ts`). It will look something like the example below:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
        APipe,
        BPipe,
        CPipe,
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
        BPipe, // <-- provide pipe here
        CPipe, // <-- provide pipe here
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```